# Redux Middleware: How to pass additional arguments to middleware

Tags: redux, middleware

I am creating a chat application with Redux + Middleware and would like to use middleware to store objects in a local storage object whenever an action of `ADD_MESSAGE` is dispatched:

```
export function storageMiddleware(store) {
return next => action => {
    const result = next(action);
    if (action.type === "ADD_MESSAGE") {
        // Add to my storage object here
    }

    return result;
};
```

}

If apply my middleware like so:

```
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, chatMiddleware)
)
```

I would like to pass in my storage object, `storage`, but can't find anywhere in the documentation how to pass in additional arguments. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add one more level of function nesting to make it work.  `redux-thunk` does the same thing:

```
// Middleware definition
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}

const thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
thunk.withExtraArgument = createThunkMiddleware;

// Middleware usage
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api))
)
```